# How to complete this proof for "If $AB$ is idempotent and $BA$ is diagonal then $BA$ is idempotent"?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ and $B$ be real matrices with dimensions $m\times n$ and $ n \times m$ respectively. Suppose $AB$ is idempotent and that $BA$ is a diagonal matrix. Prove that $BA$ is idempotent too.

I know there is an easy proof with $(BA)^2 = B \cdot AB \cdot A = B \cdot ABAB \cdot A = (BA)^3$ and since $BA$ is diagonal then it's entries must be roots of $x^3 - x^2=0$ so they must be either $1$ or $0$ and that implies what we desired.

But I wanted to complete a proof just by writing down the sigmas. I did the following calculations,

> \begin{align*} [ABAB]_{i,j} &= \sum_{r=1}^n [ABA]_{i,r} \cdot b_{r,j} \\
> &= \sum_{r=1}^n b_{r,j} \bigg( \sum_{k=1}^m [AB]_{i,k} \cdot a_{k,r} \bigg) \\ &= \sum_{r=1}^n  b_{r,j} \Bigg( \sum_{k=1}^m a_{k,r} \bigg(\sum_{l=1}^n a_{i,l} \cdot b_{l,k} \bigg) \Bigg) \\ &= \sum_{r=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^m \sum_{l=1}^n a_{i,l} \cdot b_{l,k} \cdot a_{k,r} \cdot b_{r,j} \\ &= \sum_{r=1}^n \sum_{l=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^m  a_{i,l} \cdot  (b_{l,k} \cdot a_{k,r}) \cdot b_{r,j}\end{align*}
> Since $BA$ is diagonal, if $ 1 \leq l,r \leq n$ and $ l \neq r$ then $\sum_{k=1}^m b_{l,k} a_{k,r} = 0 $. Therefore the sigma over $l$ above is nonzero only if $l =r$ so we can remove the sigma for $l$ and replace the $l$s with $r$s. and this would give
> $$= \sum_{r=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^m  a_{i,r} \cdot  b_{r,k} \cdot a_{k,r} \cdot b_{r,j} $$
> The above expression must be equal to $[AB]_{i,j} = \sum_{r=1}^n a_{i,r} \cdot b_{r,j} $ since $AB$ is idempotent. So the subtraction of these two must be zero,
> $$ \sum_{r=1}^n \bigg (a_{i,r} \cdot b_{r,j} \Big ( 1 - \sum_{k=1}^m b_{r,k} \cdot a_{k,r} \Big) \bigg) = 0. $$

And I couldn't take it further. Is there a way to complete this approach and using this calculations to complete a proof for the question? any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you want to show that $BA$ is idempotent, then you need to show that $(BA)^2 = BA$. Why are you computung $[(AB)^2]_{ij}$?

Comment: @Gabrielek You're right; but computing $ [(AB)^2]_{i,j}$ is still one way to get more information out of the assumptions of the question. Do you think it cannot be useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to prove $BA$ is idempotent explicitly writing the products you should go something like this:
Call for a moment $C := BA$, then:
$$ [(BA)^2]_{ij} = (C\cdot C)_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^m C_{ik}C_{kj} = \sum_{k=1}^m (BA)_{ik}(BA)_{kj}$$
Then, since under our hypothesis $BA$ is a diagonal matrix, we have that $(BA)_{ik} = 0 $ if $k \ne i$. This implies that
$$\sum_{k=1}^m (BA)_{ik}(BA)_{kj} = (BA)_{ii}(BA)_{ij}$$
Here notice that the last term cancels everithing unless $i = j$, thus $(C^2)_{ij} = 0$ if $i \ne j$ and this implies that $C^2$ is a diagonal matrix too.

At this point you just need to evaluate the values on the main diagonal, that are:
$$(C^2)_{ii} = \sum_{k=1}^m C_{ik}C_{ki}$$

Can you conclude from this point using the hypothes that $AB$ is idempotent?